# JQuery Sortable overlapping issue

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortable lists in two div's, each div has the overflow-y:scroll property. When I drag an item from the left div to the right div, it slides under the right edge of the left div, disappearing from view, yet everything functions as if it where there (so it can still be added to the right list etc.).

I have experimented and it seems to be an issue with setting the CSS overflow attribute on the parent div. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the sortable list, I have encountered a similar problem.

This solution worked for me.

[Dealing with overlapping jQuery sortable lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092817/dealing-with-overlapping-jquery-sortable-lists)