# jQuery sortable overflow issue in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page using three side-by-side jQuery sortables above one other.  The idea is to pick and choose from the top three lists into the bottom one.  See the example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wUXC/2/).

In Chrome, it's fine.  But in IE8, the sortables act as if the hidden portion of the top three are still there, so when you try to drop in the bottom list, it's just added back to the top list. You can get it to work by trying to drop in the margin between the top lists.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405442/jquery-sortable-overlapping-issue), but I'm not seeing any jittering like it describes, and the overlapping lists are on top of eachother, not side by side.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in [this post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortable-drag-to-another-box-but-not-sort-within-self).  It turns out that sortable wasn't really the behavior I was after for the top three side-by-side lists.  I changed these to draggable and made the bottom droppable/sortable.  Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wUXC/4/) with the solution.