# Is a jQuery Greedy Droppable Dialog possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to create a dialog that I can drop elements "in" to, but I am running into issues because the elements below it are also droppable.  Is there a way I can simulate or enhance the greedy feature on a droppable element without the nested elements (something with z-index maybe)?  Or is it possible to nest a dialog within a dialog (this might be an issue with overlapping dialogs at the same level)?

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092817/dealing-with-overlapping-jquery-sortable-lists -- I am trying to work out a solution so hopefully I can post a answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

This took me a lot of time to figure out but I have a working sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/HXRSe/

So there is a problem with having overlapping sortable lists so I had to write a rearound with the events built in. I used the `beforeStop` to find if there was a collision between the helper(item getting dragged) and a connected list. If there was a collision I append it to that new list.

Here is the jQuery code for the example:
Be sure to include jQuery Collisions: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/

```
$('#container').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable_list',
    start: function() {
        $('#popup').fadeIn();
    },
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
        var list = ui.helper.collision($('#container').data().sortable.options.connectWith);
        var thisList = $(this);
        list.each(function(index, value) {
            if($(this)[0] != thisList[0]) {
                $(this).append(ui.helper);
            }
        });
    },
    stop: function() {
        $('#popup').fadeOut();
    }
}).disableSelection();

// List to Drag items into...
$('#popup').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable_list'
}).disableSelection();
```

​And the HTML/CSS to go with it:

```
<i>Start dragging to see a pop up list.</i>

<div id="container" class="sortable_list">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="item">Item 5</div>
</div>

<div id="popup" class="sortable_list">
    Drop Items Here:
</div>​

<style type="text/css">
#container
{
    background: #cccccc;
}

.item
{
    background: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    line-height: 30px;

    cursor: hand; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

#popup
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 75px;

    display: none;
    width: 500px;

    background: #444444;
    padding: 4px;
}

</style>
```