# Sort items into fixed container with jQuery ui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, fixed

I have a problem with my sortable list. I have two container which both have sortable list inside. One of the two container have a fixed position. While I can move an item from the fixed container to the other, I cannot move an item from the not-fixed container to the fixed one.

```
$('ul').sortable({
  connectWith: $('ul'),
  items: '> li'
});

.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  left:100px;
  top:0;
}

<div class="fixed">
  <ul>
    <li>f1</li>
    <li>f2</li>
    <li>f3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="not-fixed">
  <ul>
    <li>nf1</li>
    <li>nf2</li>
    <li>nf3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see the problem there : http://jsfiddle.net/mQP8p/

The fixed container **must** be with a fixed postion (the container must follow the page vertically and horizontally)

Does someone have seen this before?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with overlapping jQuery sortable lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092817/dealing-with-overlapping-jquery-sortable-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `not-fixed` class element was not a set width so it was appearing over the `fixed` class element. This is why it was still sorting your first list even when you dragged over the `fixed` list. Try something as simple as setting the width on the `not-fixed` class.

```
.not-fixed {
   width: 50px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mQP8p/4/)

**Note:** Changing the width of your parent div will effect the area that you can drag your element. Play around with it and see what width works best for your purposes.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have told that the not-fixed container take the whole screen width and more (the page is width-endless). This is why I need a fixed panel (to follow the scroll).

While this work with the fiddle exemple, it cannot work in my project :(

Comment: Ah well that's an entirely different animal. Refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092817/dealing-with-overlapping-jquery-sortable-lists

Comment: @user1812564 No problem. Please consider marking my answer since it helped to resolve the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to make the 'non-fixed' div have `position: absolute`.
A working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mQP8p/1/